# Difference between import from "phoenix" vs import from "./socket"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phoenix-framework

I need to know please, what's the difference between

```
import {Socket} from "phoenix"
```

VS:

```
import from "./socket" ?
```

The first one has worked for me, the other did not.. where can I read bout import command?

Comment: That's just JS, not Elixir: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification